# cs50 recover, "recovered images do not match"

Tags: c, cs50, recover

My source code successfully compiles and produced in a total of 50 pictures.
However, none of the recovered images do match the original image.
All of the jpegs look like these below.
As you can see, they seem to have weird edges overlapping. 
Some of them look okay, but still fail to match the original picture.

[image]
[image]

If you can give any insight on how to debug, please let me know.

**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    BYTE buffer[512];
    char *filename[8];
    int jpeg_counter = 0;
    bool foundStartOfJPEG = false;
    FILE *img;

    // read memory card until the end of file
    while(fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, file) == 1)
    {
        // if buffer has a signature of JPEG file,
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3]) & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (foundStartOfJPEG == true)
            {
                fclose(img);
                jpeg_counter += 1;
            }

            foundStartOfJPEG = true;
            // create a file with index
            sprintf(*filename, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
            // open that file to write into it
            img = fopen(*filename, "w");
            // write the block of memory (buffer), to that file
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
        }
        else if (foundStartOfJPEG == true)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why another call to  `fread()` inside the while loop `fread()`ing already?

Comment: Thanks, I just removed the extra line of `fread()`. Now, I have 50 pictures recovered, but it does not match the original image. I will update the problem. @alk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out your code and it works when you change filename from a pointer to an array (i.e. char *filename to char filename).

Comment: Thank you, once changing my file name to an array of characters, it is fixed. However, do you know WHY having a pointer caused this problem? My understanding is, an array of character and pointer array of character, are both basically type string. Anyways, I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why the images end up distorted in the way they do but I think the use of the pointer is not correct in the first place so the error stems from that in some way. I've added another answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and incorporates the use of pointers. Here p is a pointer that points to filename. However, I think its use is redundant. Without the use of p at all, you could say that filename is a pointer that points to the first element of filename, i.e. filename[0]. So when you used char *filename[8] that was like saying filename is a pointer that points to a pointer... Hope that makes sense!

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
BYTE buffer[512];
char filename[8];
char *p = filename;
int jpeg_counter = 0;
bool foundStartOfJPEG = false;
FILE *img;

// read memory card until the end of file
while(fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, file) == 1)
{
    // if buffer has a signature of JPEG file,
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && ((buffer[3]) & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        if (foundStartOfJPEG == true)
        {
            fclose(img);
        }

        jpeg_counter += 1;
        foundStartOfJPEG = true;
        // create a file with index
        sprintf(p, "%03i.jpg", jpeg_counter);
        // open that file to write into it
        img = fopen(p, "w");
        // write the block of memory (buffer), to that file
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
    }
    else if (foundStartOfJPEG == true)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
    }
}
```